# How to collapse all headers in Word 2013?

Tags: headers, microsoft-word-2013

In Word 2013 we can collapse/expand a header.

I want to toggle the collapsable ones for all headers.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right click on a header, select `Expand/Collapse > Expand All Headings` (or `Collapse All Headings`).

Also you may like to have shortcuts for them, so follow these steps:

From the `File` menu at left-top corner, choose `Options`.

In `Word Options` window from the left column select `Customize Ribbon`.

Then in right pane look at bottom of pane, you'll see `Keyboard shortcuts:`; click `Customize...`

In `Customize Keyboard` window, under `Categories:`, scroll down and select `All Commands`

Then click under `Commands:` and type in `ExpandAllHeadings` (By typing two first letters you'll get it)

Then put cursor in `Press new shortcut key` box and hold `Alt` key with `E` from keyboard, then click `Assign`. Now we have `Alt+E` shortcut for Expanding all headings.

Again under `Commands:` type in `CollapseAllHeadings`, and follow steps just same as above, but use `Alt+C` for it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Iman. Do we have a hotkey for that?

Comment: Not by default, but we can assign one. I will modify the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To collapse/expand all of a *specific* heading

From the `Styles` section in the `Home` ribbon, right click the specific heading style and choose `Select All x Instance(s)`; this will select the text in the body of the document:

[image: shows the Select All x Instance(s) menu item when right clicking a heading style]

In the body, right click any of the selected text/headings and choose `Expand Heading` or `Collapse Heading` (*not* "All Headings"):

[image: shows the Expand Heading and Collapse heading menu items when right-clicking a heading in the body]

Comment: Hey, that was very helpful.  I see that this post is quite old, but maybe you're still around.  Any idea how to collapse all headings of a specific name?  As an example, for each Heading 1, I have a couple Heading 2.  And within each Heading 2, I have a couple of Heading 3.  Every single Heading 2 has the *same* Heading 3s.... I want to collapse all of the Heading 3 named "Interpretation", but NOT the Heading 3 named "Checking"

Comment: @MikeChristiansen Perhaps you could create two different headings with the same style to accomplish that, otherwise I think you'd have to go the route of writing a macro.

Comment: I've decided to use a different approach.  Going to store the data in XML, and use XSLT to generate an HTML page.  Use a different XSLT to see different things, rather than collapsing headings.  Really is a better way forward anyway, for this project.